# Are public IP addresses always static / private IP addresses only dynamic?

Tags: networking, ip

I am new to networking. This sounds like a basic question but I have not been able to find a clear answer. Servers and Modems have public IP addresses from what I know. I also have found out that Servers and Modems IP addresses are static.

Personal Computers and Smart Phones connected to Wifi on a private network have private IP addresses and are dynamic.

Can someone give me an example of a device with a public IP address that is also dynamic? Or a device with a private IP address that is also static? So far I haven't come across any devices in either of these categories.

Comment: IP, itself, has no idea about public or private addresses, they are all simply IP addresses to IP, and there is nothing inherent to say that this one is private and that one is public. The private IP address blocks are purely an artificial designation that ISPs will not forward packets in certain ranges on the public Internet. Any IP address can be assigned as a static address or dynamically. It makes sense to statically assign addresses to which others  need to regularly connect, but dynamic addressing is easier and scales better. The assignment method is what makes sense for the situation.

Answer (score 0):

Private address are:

```
192.168.x.x
10.x.x.x
172.16.x.x
```

```
    https://www.arin.net/knowledge/address_filters.html
```

The rest are all public addresses.

Now relating to static IP or dynamic ip addresses.

Static IP are ip's that are assign ex. a Web-Cam in your house to see your car. so you know the ip address and you can always connect.

Dynamic IP address are IP's that are assign to the hosts if they are available. For this we use DHCP (Dynamic host configuration protocol). This service assign ip address in your network, as I mention before it will assign ip's to your host if they are available. IPs have a lease time and they will expire and then you request an dhcp renew to get the same or a new ip address.

```
    https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_Host_Configuration_Protocol
```